# Pandas comparing list across column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a certain business requirement for which I am having trouble in implementing a faster solution (current solution takes 3 hrs per iteration)

Eg: Say I have a df

[image]

and there's a list :

```
l = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]
```

To do:

1. Compare all the list values across customer and check if they exist or not
2. If they exist then find the corresponding min and max date1

Currently the pseudo working code I have is :

```
for each customer:
     group by customer and add column having code column into a list
     for each list value:
        check if particular list value exists (in case check if [a,b,c] exists in first loop)
        if exists:
           check for min date by group etc
```

This multiple for loop is taking too long to execute since I have 100k+ customers.
Any way to further improve this? I already eliminated one for loop reducing time from 10hrs to 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified my approach.
Instead of looping through each customer (I have 100k+ customers)
I looped through each list :
checked if customers were present or not and then looped through filtered customers

This reduced the time by a couple of hours.
Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
```

Firstly flatten your list:

```
from pandas.core.common import flatten
l=list(flatten(l))
```

Then do boolean masking to check if the customer exists or not in your dataframe:

```
newdf=df[df['code'].isin(l)]
```

Finally do `groupby()`:

```
#The below code groupby 'code':
newdf=newdf.groupby('code').agg(max_date1=('date1','max'),min_date1=('date1','min'))

#If You want to groupby customerid and code then use:
newdf=newdf.groupby(['customerid','code']).agg(max_date1=('date1','max'),min_date1=('date1','min'))
```

Now If you print `newdf` you will get your desired output